# NODE.JS - OpenShift 503 Service is Temporarily Unavilable: Server.js and Package.json files are fine

Tags: node.js, openshift, server

Project running on a Node.js Server:

I'm going crazy over here. I can't figure out why I am getting a 503 error when I have done exactly what Open Shift instructs to do.

**Server.js:**

```
 var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;
 var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1';

server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function(){
 console.log("Listening on " + server_ip_address + ", 
 server_port " +server_port);
});
```

**package.json:**

```
 {
 "scripts": {
   "start": "supervisor server.js"
 },
 "main": "server.js"
 }
```

I have gone through my logs and everything, and it says there is an issue at line 5 on server.js. How is that so? Am I going crazy, or am I missing something? The NPM modules are cleared, and the application says it is fine.

This is not a replica of another post, because I have done all of those.

**Server Log Trail Error:**

```
 ReferenceError: server is not defined
     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/lib/openshift/550764f6e0b8cd8a8a00007e/app-  root/runtime/repo/server.js:4:1)
     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
     at startup (node.js:119:16)
     at node.js:902:3
 DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 8
 DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
 /var/lib/openshift/550764f6e0b8cd8a8a00007e/app-       root/runtime/repo/server.js:4
 server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function(){
 ^
```

I have no idea what is going on. I keep getting a server is undefined issue, and everything is done correctly from what I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a string opened at the end of line 5 and you never close it. change it to

```
var server_port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080
var server_ip_address = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'

server.listen(server_port, server_ip_address, function(){
 console.log("Listening on " + server_ip_address 
           + ", server_port " + server_port);
});
```

and you should be good to go

Comment: There is a new build going on now. I was actually missing three semicolons; for the variables and the function. (brain dead...) Let's see if this works. I HOPE IT DOES

Comment: @ChrisCooley hope it worked. FYI semicolons in JS are optional in almost all cases, so that definitely wouldn't cause any problems for you (although I and probably a majority of people who write javascript would say you should use them for stylistic purposes)

Comment: man, i keep getting the same error. It says @jtmarmon that "server is undefined"

Comment: ah. yes see @corey112358's answer. my eyes just darted to the glaring issue without reading the rest of your code

Answer (score 1):

If that is what your file actually looks like, it looks like you are missing a chunk of code:

```
var ipaddress = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port      = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Received request for ' + request.url);
    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      response.write("Welcome to Node.js on OpenShift!\n\n");
      response.end("Thanks for visiting us! \n");
});

server.listen( port, ipaddress, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ' Server is listening on port 8080');
});
```

That code is referenced from this quickstart: https://github.com/openshift-quickstart/openshift-nodejs-http-and-websocket-example/blob/master/server.js

The references server.js includes some websocket code also, but you can ignore that (unless you want to use it, that's fine too)